# 2 OneToOneField defined for two tables. One got deleted but not other

Tags: django, django-models

I have defined two OneToOneFields in my model as below:

```
class StudentCrossMap(models.Model):
    rfId = models.OneToOneField(StudentDailyTrans)
    studentId = models.OneToOneField(StudentMaster)
```

When I apply delete on the model above giving `rfId`, the entry related to it in `StudentDailyTrans` gets deleted, BUT the one in `StudentMaster`did not gets removed.

Ideally, if I am deleting the object from `StudentCrossMap` it should not be deleting the entries from mapped tables as those tables are not dependent on `StudentCrossMap` table.

Please advise if I am doing something wrong.

*Edit: Related tables

```
class StudentDailyTrans(models.Model):
    rfId = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    schoolId = models.ForeignKey(SchoolMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=False)
    fromTime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    toTime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    totalSwipeInstance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lastUpdateTs = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class StudentMaster(models.Model):
    studentId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    schoolId = models.ForeignKey(SchoolMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parentId = models.ForeignKey(ParentMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class SchoolMaster(models.Model):
    schoolId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    subsStrtDt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class ParentMaster(models.Model):
    parentId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parentName = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='parent')
```

Comment: post the related tables aslo

Comment: @e4c5 added tables, please check

Comment: I am really sorry but I can't make much sense out of your models. The new ones you posted refer to others which you haven't posted.

Comment: @e4c5 apologies for inconvenience. Just added dependent tables.

Comment: this 'Master' does that mean a school teacher or the old fasions 'Master table' stuff?

Comment: @e4c5 master is nothing but keeping track the entries. Crossmap provides the mapping for StudentId and rfid

Comment: @e4c5 I am very new to django and doing this as demo project. If you see any improvement, then that is also welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood what you have posted correctly, you are better off with a design like this.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(SchoolMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rf = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
```

This is essentially, your old `StudentMaster` model. I have renamed it to Student. I have also renamed the field names to comply with the usual django naming convention (school instead of school_id for the foreign key)

Now you can  delete `StudentDailyTrans` and `StudentCrossMap` we are saving the same data more efficiently and yet without redundancy. And that eliminates the problem you asked about!!

You will agree with me that the code is a lot more readable.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have added more fields StudentDailyTrans. In that I am tracking swipe instances of in-out of student. If I delete that table then with single table it willbe difficult to track one.

Comment: Ok I got your solution. ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, in my design why that uneven delete is happening. Can you please tell me the reson behind that?

Comment: sorry i couldn't figure that out either,